# CPU cycles in cloud

Tags: cloud, cpu, load-balancing

I am basic learner of cloud computing. How the CPU cycles are allocated in cloud computing load balancing technique.how load balancing is done in cloud computing

Answer (score 0):

Not very much sure but basically load balancing works on the basis of roundrobin technique so the distribution should be almost equal .

Main reasons load balancing-

- Web server is not able to handle the traffic
- intolerance to an outage if one web server fails

Jelastic helped me for load balancing .
please follow the following links , this might help you to understand-

> http://jelastic.com/docs/http-load-balancing
>
> http://jelastic.com/docs/tcp-load-balancing